# Is it more proper to use gcc or g++ while compiling a question in the C Language tag?

Tags: discussion

I answer a question with a C language tag and got down-voted for using #define rather than const or static for defining constants. One of the constants is defined in terms of the other constants. When using #define this compiles fine using gcc, when using const I get a compilation error. gcc forces the use of Standard C, g++ compiles everything as C++. Should g++ be used over gcc at all times? There are 2 things I should be down voted for on the answer (2 warning messages are generated) but what I was down voted for was the use of #define over const or static.

I asked a question about proper usage of #define versus const on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237841/how-to-define-a-static-const-using-previously-defined-constants-in-c. The answer was to use #define.

Comment: This is about Stack Overflow, not Code Review. You picked the wrong meta.

Comment: Is [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123848/validating-e-mail-address-input-in-c/123856#comment230838_123856) the comment you are referring to?

Comment: The first comment and the fifth comment.

Comment: The original question that caused me to ask the question on stackoverflow is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123848/validating-e-mail-address-input-in-c/123856#123856

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no site policy on which compiler to use or assume.  (I've removed that tag from your question.)

Meta is not a good place for debating the technical merit of an answer. It could be a place to raise awareness of systematic abuse of voting, but your post isn't about that.  Answers can be discussed in comments; if it's too complicated to be discussed in comments, then in chat.

Answer (score 2):

#### Which compiler should I use when reviewing an answer?

As [200_success's answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6677/36366) states, there is no site policy for which compiler to use or assume.  This isn't just for [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c), but for everything.

However, some questions will specify that the asker is using a particular compiler.  If you come across one of those questions, you should use & assume that compiler.

Otherwise, if the question doesn't specify a compiler, then your answer should highlight any parts of it which are compiler-specific.  If you do this, users using that compiler can choose to take your advice, and users using other compilers can safely skip over that section of your answer.